# UPS/FedEx shipment request special characters

Tags: utf-8, label, fedex, ups

Recently I've been working on implementation of Label generation for FedEx and UPS couriers using they external service. I have a problem with special characters printed on label. Within response I'm getting correct text but on Label all special chars are replaced by dummy signs. According UPS&FedEx docs they perfectly supports such characters on labels till they are passed as UTF-8 and encoding node in xml is present (pointing to UTF-8).

Did anyone faced similar problem? Maybe there is an official note from them that they'r not supporting such case that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

UPS and FedEx APIs supports only Latin-1 chars. Dummy chars were assigned by auto utf-8 cast in one of internal methods (dicttoxml) that results in double UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I wonder if FedEx or UPS XML would support [character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) such as `&agrave;` for `à`.